# Where to implement Cost function with regularization in code?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, regularization

I have implemented my neural network and now I need to get Cost function and Error function after each epoch to visualize learning process.

I don't know where is the place I can calculate cost function. Is it just in the output layer? I also have regularization. I am minimizing this function:

$$E(w) + \frac{\lambda}{2}W^2$$

regarding updating the weights there is no problem. But for getting  this value on my training set and test set I don't know how to implement it. in the output layer I don't have any weights. How should I calculate the part about weights in my cost function?